# Set VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG for binary value

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I get this error when I attempt to execute my Kafka producer application:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert value of class [B to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer specified in value.serializer
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
> at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer.serialize(IntegerSerializer.java:19)
> at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:62)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:894)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:856)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:743)
> at com.cme.pe.ProducerDemo.main(ProducerDemo.java:50)

The issue is that my `VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG` property is `StringSerializer` but my `KafkaProducer` and `Producer record` have a binary value

```
properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());

KafkaProducer<String, byte[]> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, byte[]>(properties);
        
ProducerRecord<String, byte[]> record = new ProducerRecord<String, byte[]>("foo", allBytes);
```

What should my `VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG` be set to for this?

Answer (score 0):

`ByteArraySerializer.class.getName()`

The line should be

```
properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArraySerializer.class.getName());
```